# Are there data structures in java whose size isn't limited by MAX_INT?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, bigdata

The size of a [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#size()) in java is limited by the max integer value. Are there a more bigdata-friendly Queues or similar data structures?

Comment: I didn't even know the size was limited. Is that just the restriction of the `size` method by being defined to return an `int`?

Comment: `Queue` is an interface. If you meant the `ArrayBlockingQueue` that's linked, that's  bounded. When you looked at other implementations of `Queue` in the documentation you linked, what did you  find?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis what other implementations? That's basically what I am asking for

Comment: @0x90 take a look at "All Known Implementing Classes" in [Queue's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). And those are only the implementations provided in java's own classes.

Comment: The ones in the documentation you linked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis size is always `int` for all the unlined data structures of the Queue (Linked List, List, ArrayList)

Comment: The built-in Queue has a limit of MAX_INTEGER, but there are other implementations. A search for "java big queue" reveals https://github.com/bulldog2011/bigqueue, among others. Note that I make no claims about the quality of those implementations.

Comment: @JimMischel *"**The** built-in Queue"??* Java has more than one `Queue` implementation, e.g. `LinkedList` is a `Queue` implementation, and it doesn't *limit* the number of elements in the queue, although `size()` and `isEmpty()` don't work right if you add more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements.